# Shopify checkout parameters

Tags: shopify, shopping-cart, shopify-template

I'm working with a client who wants to have an order shipping address be filled on the cart page. I found that you can do it like this https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/cart/use-permalinks-to-preload-cart, so I added few input fields to my cart form with name attributes (e.g. name=" checkout[shipping_address][address1]"). Everything worked ok for me but not for my client. He writes that info auto-filled but it is from memory from other Shopify orders he has made on other websites.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter of HTML. All you have to do is to set autocomplete input parameter on off like that:

```
<input type="text" name="checkout[shipping_address][address1]" autocomplete="off" id="customerAddress1">
```

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: I understand how to add parameters to the form. The problem is that shopify  sometimes ignores them and adds different shipping parameters from the past purchases.

Comment: Right - but what Alice is pointing out is that it's probably not Shopify doing that, it's most likely the user's browser being too smart for its own good and auto-completing the form with the address the browser already knows (and thus overwriting the pre-filled fields that you tried to pass along).  One way to test this hypothesis would be to get your client to try your link using a computer or browser that they haven't made a Shopify order on before

Answer (score 0):

What it's happening here is that your customer is already logged and Shopify checkout is autofilling the customer address info on first step and skipping to checkout step number 2. You need to include `&step=contact_information` to Shopify checkout always render on first step and then permalink should work regardless if is logged or not.

So you should try adding this input on your cart template:

`<input type="hidden" name="checkout[step] value="contact_information">`